# How to use Angular $http with typescript generics

Tags: angularjs, generics, typescript, promise

I'm trying to return a generic  promise in the following way

```
public getUserPreferences: () => ng.IPromise <string> = () => {
        var promise = this.makeRequest<string>('http://someurl.com',null)
            .then((response:string) => {
                    let res: string = response;
                    return res;
                }
            )
            .catch((error) => {
            });

        return promise;
    };

        public makeRequest<T>(וrl: string, data?: any,
                          config?: any, verb?: HttpMethod): ng.IPromise<T> {
        // Cache key contains both request url and data
        var cacheKey = url + '*' + JSON.stringify(data);

        var deferred = this.$q.defer();
        var httpRequest: any;
        var responseData: T;
        var start = new Date().getTime();

        // Trying to retrieve cache data if needed
        if (!config || config.cache != false) {
            responseData = this.cacheService.get(cacheKey);
        }

        if (responseData) {
            deferred.resolve(responseData);
        }
        else {
            switch (verb) {
                case HttpMethod.GET:
                    httpRequest = this.$http.get(url, config);
                    break;
                case HttpMethod.POST:
                    httpRequest = this.$http.post(url, data, config);
                    break;
                case HttpMethod.PATCH:
                    httpRequest = this.$http.patch(url, data, config);
                    break;
                default:
                    httpRequest = this.$http.post(url, data, config);
                    break;

            }

            httpRequest
                .then((res: any) => {
                    responseData = res.data;
                    this.cacheService.put(cacheKey, responseData);
                    deferred.resolve(responseData);
                })
                .catch((error: any) => {
                    deferred.reject(error);
                });
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

But I'm getting the following error on getUserPreferences:

> Error:(132, 9) TS2322: Type '() => IPromise' is not assignable
>   to type '() => IPromise'.  Type 'IPromise' is not
>   assignable to type 'IPromise'.  Type 'void' is not assignable
>   to type 'string'.

Comment: remove catch block from `getUserPreferences`

Comment: @AlekseyL. thanks! it works! But how can I catch the exception?

Comment: If this is right place to handle exception and you don't want to return anything in case of exception - you should define return type as `ng.IPromise <string|void>`. Beware if you're catching exception here the promise will be always resolved as successful.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the problem is that you never resolve promise with `responseData`: no `resolve(responseData)` meant that promise was resolving implicitly with `undefined`.

Try this:

```
public makeRequest<T>(url:string, data?: any): ng.IPromise<T> {
    return this.$http.post(url, data)
           .then((res: any) => {
               return res.data;
           });
}
```

I also removed redundant deferred object, which you don't need because you can directly return promise.

Another difference. I dropped `catch` block because it's better to have it at the end of the promise chain (in `getUserPreferences`).

Comment: My real makeRequest method is more complicated because first I'm trying to retrieve the value from cache if it doesn't exist on cache I want to add it to cache and only then send the response, I will update my question